# Why does this "-e" option for echo get written to a file (although not enclosed in double quotes)?

Tags: python, echo

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run
from sys import modules

def main():
  doas()

def doas():
  ch = input("Ready to proceed with setting up doas?[Y/n]?")
  if ch == 'y':
    run("sudo passwd", shell=True)#If you would prefer to access the root account with su or by logging in directly, you must set a root password with "sudo passwd".
    run("sudo apt install -y doas", shell=True) 
    run("""echo -e "permit $(whoami) as root 
permit root as $(whoami)
permit nopass root as $(whoami)"|sudo tee /etc/doas.conf""", shell=True) and run("doas apt -y purge sudo", shell=True)
    print("doas set up.")
  else:
    print("Run me again when you are ready.")
```

The problem with this code is that it places the option `-e` in `doas.conf`, like so:

```
-e permit jim as root
permit root as jim
permit nopass root as jim
```

while I need `doas.conf` to look like so:

```
permit jim as root
permit root as jim
permit nopass root as jim
```

I know that the easiest quick fix is simply not to use `-e` with `echo`. Is there any other way I can resolve this issue?

Why does `-e` end up written into `doas.conf` if it is not enclosed within double quotes?
When I run

```
echo -e "permit $(whoami) as root 
permit root as $(whoami)
permit nopass root as $(whoami)"|tee doas.conf
```

from my shell (Bash), then all works fine and I get the desired result.
Why is it different from Python?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and my echo seems to support -e, e.g. echo -e "a\nb\nc" it prints them letters with newlines.

Comment: What does `/bin/echo -e hello` output on your system?

Comment: @Kusalananda It outputs `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Because different implementations of `echo` either support or don't support options like `-e` and `-n`, and either process or don't process C-style backslash-escapes like `\n` and `\t`.

[A standard `echo` does *not* take options](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

> The *echo* utility shall not recognize the "--" argument in the manner specified by Guideline 10 of XBD Utility Syntax Guidelines; "--" shall be recognized as a string operand.
>
> Implementations shall not support any options.

Use `printf` instead. See: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)

---

Quotes (double or single) have nothing to do with it, as they are processed by the shell before the command runs and gets a chance to process its options. In all of

```
echo -e foo
echo "-e" foo
echo '-e' foo
```

the `echo` command sees the two arguments `-e` and `foo`.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and my `echo` seems to support `-e`, e.g. `echo -e "a\nb\nc"` it prints them letters with newlines.

Comment: @JohnSmith, well. The one that your Python script starts obviously doesn't. The point is that there's no single `echo`, but that every implementation is potentially different. So, don't use `echo` if you care about the output being what you want, there's a better and more compatible alternative available in `printf`.

Comment: @JohnSmith, if you want to go there, you probably have not one, but three `echo` implementations on Ubuntu: the one in Bash, the one in Dash, and the one in `/bin/echo`. And yes, they're all different.

Comment: @ilkkachu four, with busybox  usually being installed by default too.